# Why does the buttons inside my scroll view does not fill the width?

Tags: android, xml

I'm having a hard time figuring it out and the slowness of the emulator adds to it.
Can someone give me some pointers here..

What i intent to do is pushing the width of those boxes, what usually happen is that the buttons just wraps up and leaves an empty space on the right side.
heres the xml code i've been fixing for like forever....

```
    <ScrollView
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="150dp" >

      <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="1" >

        <TableRow>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bOne"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Radio Buttons" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bTwo"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="List View" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bThree"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bFour"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bFive"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Hey, that's a pretty surprising result.  I get the same thing when I look at your xml in my emulator.  I would have expected the buttons to fill the whole way across.  I know its no help to you, but at least I'm seeing what you're seeing.

Comment: Have you tried a `LinearLayout` with horizontal orientation? You should be able to put all the butons in one row and not wrap lines.

Comment: Ill try it @Rarw ,My `LinearLayout`  is oriented vertically, hope to fix it soon

Comment: Guys sorry for my stupid questions..

I've fix the problem..

What i did was i put the buttons on the linear layout vertically then putted it inside the scroll view,then it worked.. 

thanks guys!!

Answer (score 0):

In the tablelayout you have android:stretchColumns="1"
Columns starts to index from 0, so either remove the strechcolumns or replace it's value to 0.